# Contol mediaplayer from keyguard

Tags: android, widget, keyguard

I need control mediaplayer application from keyguard (lock screen).

- notification playing song
- play/pause control
- album image preview

But i don't know how.

```
public static void putNotification(Context mcontent, String text) {

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(mcontent, MainActivity.class);

    resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mcontent, 0, resultIntent, 0);

    mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) mcontent.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mcontent);

    mBuilder.setContentTitle(mcontent.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name_inside))
            .setContentText(text)                   
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)   
            .setLargeIcon(bm)                       
            .setTicker(text)                        
            .setAutoCancel(false)                   
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)                  
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

    mNotifyManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());


}
```

I think android have simple function like this for notify keyguard.

Comment: Post your code so far and/or display that you've put some effort into finding the solution.

Comment: I have no code, now my app can send nitification. I add code to my message.